# Efficient recurring tasks in celery?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, celerybeat, recurring-events

I have ~250,000 recurring tasks each day; about a fifth of which might be updated with different scheduled datetimes each day.

Can this be done efficiently in Celery? - I am worried about this from celery's [beat.py](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/beat.py#L204):

```
    def tick(self):
        """Run a tick, that is one iteration of the scheduler.

           Executes all due tasks.

       """
        remaining_times = []
        try:
            for entry in values(self.schedule):
                next_time_to_run = self.maybe_due(entry, self.publisher)
                if next_time_to_run:
                    remaining_times.append(next_time_to_run)
        except RuntimeError:
            pass

        return min(remaining_times + [self.max_interval])
```

Comment: That's about 3 things a second, although I assume these things will be clustered less nicely. So: try it with very very lightweight tasks and run top. 250k isn't an enormous number.

Comment: We may be able to rewrite this to use the same algorithm as the timer which uses a heapq.  Probably at the cost of space and a more expensive update for runtime schedules, but I think it's possible.  Something like: at startup generate the heapq by calling is_due for all entries.  when a entry is popped off the heapq and ran the heap is again updated with the next `.is_due()` value.  If the schedule is changed (e.g. if an entry is changed when using the database backend scheduler) then the heap must be regenerated from scratch.

Comment: Yeah, that would indeed be a much better approach :)