# Creating a reminder task in langchain

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model

I'm trying to create a studying tutor with LLMs and langchain. What I'm looking for is that the app reminds the student once in a while during the conversation if he/she has done his/her homework, and based on the answer remind him/her later or don't remind her again. I'm looking for a clue on how to achieve such a thing. Thanks in advance

Comment: A related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274417/schedule-reminder-for-recurring-event). Does the reminder need to be in langchain? I am asking this because you would be having a UI/Application that the user can interact with

Comment: Thanks, it's not related to the environment of my app, my app is an LLM based app, the logic will be different